# How to set image source in wpf, both are in dll?

Tags: wpf

I'm facing a problem regarding Image source in wpf usercontrol.

A solution contains

1. WPF application
2. Class library.

Details:

1. WPF application is referanced to class library. In this a Usercontrol from library is added to grid child of window1 from code.
2. Class library contains a UserControl which has a Image control and a png image. png image is added to resources of class library project.

I've tried this, but not working

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/refresh_blue.png"/>
```

Problem: I'm not able to set the .png image to Image control source.

please help me

Please find the project at this [WpfApplication2.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kgznabhzlwau4s/WpfApplication2.zip) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
... Source="Resources/refresh_blue.png" ...
```

You are referencing a resource of the same assembly. So you don't have to specify extra information.

In your project, leave the `Loaded` events away and specify the control in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cl="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary1;assembly=ClassLibrary1"
    Title="Window1" Height="246" Width="348">
    <Grid Name="maiGrid">
        <cl:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```